# В чем сила static?

Tags: c#, static

Для чего модификатор static и какие последствия влекут за собой его отсутствие в данном коде?

```
class Program
{
    static string userName;
    private const string host = "127.0.0.1";
    private const int port = 8888;
    static TcpClient client;
    static NetworkStream stream;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите свое имя: ");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        client = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            client.Connect(host, port); 
            stream = client.GetStream(); 

            string message = userName;
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
            receiveThread.Start(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать, {0}", userName);
            SendMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    static void SendMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите сообщение: ");

        while (true)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }

    static void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[64]; 
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подключение прервано!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    static void Disconnect()
    {
        if(stream!=null)
            stream.Close();
        if(client!=null)
            client.Close();
        Environment.Exit(0); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Плюс статика -- хранится не для каждого экземпляра класса, а один раз (экономит память компьютера). Минус статика -- плохая тестируемость, не замокать. А вообще поиском по сайту куча тем уже есть, читали?

Comment: Хм, _сила_? Статику никто не может сказать: "Я твой отец". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, для начала формальная часть.

В `static void Main(string[] args)` модификатор `static` обязателен, т. к. функция `Main` должна быть статической. Остальные случаи употребления `static` нужны потому, что в вашем коде не создаётся ни одного экземпляра вашего класса, а значит, доступа к нестатическим полям/свойствам/методам просто нету.

Теперь смысловая.

Говорят, что C# — объектно-ориентированный язык. Это лишь наполовину правда. Например, на нём вполне можно писать в процедурном стиле, что и демонстрирует ваш код.

Для маленьких программ наподобие вашей можно и проигнорировать объектную ориентацию, и считать класс всего лишь бессмысленным контейнером функций/свойств. Но когда программа становится большой, стоит наделить классы смыслом: заставить их представлять собой какие-то объекты реального мира.
Так вот, в этом случае начинает проявляться разница.

Обыкновенные, нестатические поля/методы представляют собой данные/действия, относящиеся к конкретному объекту. Например, если у вас есть класс `Car`, у него может быть нестатические поля `double weight;` или там `double currentVelocity;`, и нестатический метод `Accelerate()`.

А статические поля/методы представляют собой данные/действия, относящиеся ко всем объектам данного класса. Например, для класса `Car` это может быть `GetPossibleFuelTypes()` (получить список возможных видов топлива).

---

Резюмируя:

- Для маленьких программ: вы можете из статических методов класса получать доступ только к статическим данным. Чтобы работать с экземплярными данными, вам придётся завести экземпляр класса.
- Для больших программ: руководствуйтесь смыслом ваших данных. Для данных/действий конкретного объекта нужно использовать нестатические поля/методы, а для данных/действий, относящихся ко всем объектам одновременно, статические.